# function for iterating occurrences of a timestamp in a column by day

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R sorted in descending order by timestamp in column A (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm 24h). I am looking to create in column B a running count of timestamps in column A occurring since midnight for each unique day. I would like to produce the following outcome below:

Example:

```
| Column A        | Column B |
|-----------------|----------|
| 9/26/2019 23:29 | 4        |
| 9/26/2019 17:29 | 3        |
| 9/26/2019 8:29  | 2        |
| 9/26/2019 1:10  | 1        |
| 9/25/2019 15:21 | 4        |
| 9/25/2019 10:19 | 3        |
| 9/25/2019 5:29  | 2        |
| 9/25/2019 0:29  | 1        |
```

I have solved this in Excel by using a countif function for the unique mm/dd/yyyy value in Col A. I have not been successful to find an R equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`, we can first convert `ColumnA` to `POSIXct` format, group by date and then assign `rank` in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(ColumnA = as.POSIXct(ColumnA, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC")) %>%
  #Can also use lubridate mdy_hm
  #mutate(ColumnA = lubridate:: mdy_hm(ColumnA)) %>%
  group_by(group = as.Date(ColumnA)) %>%
  mutate(new_col = rank(ColumnA)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  ColumnA             ColumnB new_col
#  <dttm>                <int>   <dbl>
#1 2019-09-26 23:29:00       4       4
#2 2019-09-26 17:29:00       3       3
#3 2019-09-26 08:29:00       2       2
#4 2019-09-26 01:10:00       1       1
#5 2019-09-25 15:21:00       4       4
#6 2019-09-25 10:19:00       3       3
#7 2019-09-25 05:29:00       2       2
#8 2019-09-25 00:29:00       1       1
```

Kept both the columns for comparison purposes.

---

If the rows are always in descending order as mentioned in the post, we can also do

```
df %>%
  mutate(ColumnA = as.POSIXct(ColumnA, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC")) %>%
  group_by(group = as.Date(ColumnA)) %>%
  mutate(new_col = n() : 1)
  #OR
  #mutate(new_col = n() - row_number() + 1)
  #OR
  #mutate(new_col = order(ColumnA))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ColumnA = structure(c(7L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 
4L, 1L), .Label = c("9/25/2019 0:29", "9/25/2019 10:19", "9/25/2019 15:21", 
"9/25/2019 5:29", "9/26/2019 1:10", "9/26/2019 17:29", "9/26/2019 23:29", 
"9/26/2019 8:29"), class = "factor"), ColumnB = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the input shown in reproducible form in the Note at the end, create a POSIXct version of column `A` in `A` and then compute the `rank` within `Date` using `ave`.  No packages are used.

```
A <- as.POSIXct(DF$A, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "GMT")
data.frame(A, B = ave(as.numeric(A), as.Date(A), FUN = rank))
```

giving:

```
                    A B
1 2019-09-26 23:29:00 4
2 2019-09-26 17:29:00 3
3 2019-09-26 08:29:00 2
4 2019-09-26 01:10:00 1
5 2019-09-25 15:21:00 4
6 2019-09-25 10:19:00 3
7 2019-09-25 05:29:00 2
8 2019-09-25 00:29:00 1
```

Note that time series in R are normally stored in ascending order, not descending.

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "| A        | B |
| 9/26/2019 23:29 | 4        |

| 9/26/2019 17:29 | 3        |

| 9/26/2019 8:29  | 2        |

| 9/26/2019 1:10  | 1        |

| 9/25/2019 15:21 | 4        |

| 9/25/2019 10:19 | 3        |

| 9/25/2019 5:29  | 2        |

| 9/25/2019 0:29  | 1        |"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, sep = "|", header = TRUE)["A"]
```